# Use nested decended enum cases as parent enum cases

Tags: arrays, swift, types, enums, type-conversion

In the popular board game *Monopoly*, players have the opportunity to buy/trade different properties, and when they monopolize a certain neighborhood, they can build houses. I am trying to express all of these properties as a nested enumeration in Swift, but when it comes to expressing a player's properties in an Array, I'm stumped.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
enum Property {
    enum Brown {
        case mediterranean, baltic
    }

    enum LightBlue {
        case oriental, vermont, connecticuit
    }

    enum pink {
        case stCharles, states, virginia
    }
    ...
}

var properties: [Property] = [
    Property.Brown.baltic, // ERROR: Cannot convert value of type 'Property.Brown' to expected element type 'Property'
    Property.Brown.mediterranean
]
```

As you can see, I cannot store these Properties in a [Property] Array, because a Property.Brown isn't a Property (understandable). What would I need to change to be able to store `Property.<Insert Neighborhood Here>`s in an array? I understand that an [Any] would work, but I am concerned about type safety, so this won't work.

**Edit 05 July 2018, 13:18 PDT**
I am writing a program that will act as the bank for a Monopoly game and need a way to determine which players (or the bank) owns properties. I'm currently Playgrounding and prototyping to figure out what works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know,

> because a Property.Brown isn't a Property (understandable).

You may need a type common to your `Property.Brown`, `Property. LightBlue`, ...

Maybe you can use a protocol just for storing them in an Array:

```
protocol PropertyEnums {}

enum Property {
    enum Brown: PropertyEnums {
        case mediterranean, baltic
    }

    enum LightBlue: PropertyEnums {
        case oriental, vermont, connecticuit
    }

    //...
}

var properties: [PropertyEnums] = [
    Property.Brown.baltic,
    Property.Brown.mediterranean,
    //...
]
```

But I cannot be sure if this might be the best solution for you, as you are not showing the use cases of `properties`.

---

Something like this might be better for some use cases:

```
enum Property {
    enum Brown {
        case mediterranean, baltic
    }

    enum LightBlue {
        case oriental, vermont, connecticuit
    }

    //...

    case brown(Brown)
    case lightBlue(LightBlue)
    //...
}

var properties: [Property] = [
    .brown(.baltic),
    .brown(.mediterranean),
    //...
]
```

---

Please show us how do you want to use your `properties`.

Comment: Edited question